# WGet downloads content of other directories as well

Tags: wget

I am trying to run this command to get the files from directory name 156, but it downloads the contents from the sub-directories of Output directory as well.

```
wget -r -np -nH --cut-dirs=5 -R index.html -R '*.md5,*.sha1' http://servername:8081/ART/simple/Reposiotry/Output/156 -P Artifacts -o Output.log
```

Looking at the logs, I see the contents of 156 is downloaded, however, it also downloads the content of 155 and the original files gets replaces with the files from 155.

Any help which will help me just get the files from 156 and no other parent directories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the '/' at the end of the syntax fixed the problem. So my current syntax is

```
wget -r -np -nH --cut-dirs=5 -R index.html -R '*.md5,*.sha1' http://servername:8081/ART/simple/Reposiotry/Output/156/ -P Artifacts -o Output.log
```